# "ar" tag on stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

[ar](/questions/tagged/ar) is being used on Stack Overflow both to refer to the unix archiver utility ar(1),  and, more frequently, as a synonym for [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality).

Should [ar](/questions/tagged/ar) be removed from questions about augmented reality (with [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) added to replace it where it's not already there), removed from both with a new less-ambiguous tag (although I'm at a loss to suggest one...) added to the ar(1) questions, or something else?

There are only 37 questions with the tag, and I'd be happy to implement the consensus change manually myself (and to draft a tag wiki entry, although I don't have the privileges to edit it directly).

Comment: I'd be happy to help (once others agree)

Comment: This is a good idea. The tag augmented-reality should be the only one for this subject to avoid confusion.

Comment: I agree with `ar` for the util and `augmented-reality` for itself.

Comment: Isn't `ar` for the sound that pirates make?

Comment: @Marcello: that's "arr!"

Comment: I've run into the same problem with the [arc] tag, which people are now using for Apple's new automatic reference counting technology.  I've been retagging many of those to [automatic-ref-counting] to avoid confusion with all the other "arc" topics.  Generally, I think we should use full names of technologies for tags, rather than shorthand abbreviations.

Comment: @Brad: It almost certainly doesn't help that the tag wiki for arc says it's automatic reference counting. wtf?

Comment: @Wooble - Thanks for pointing that out.  I've since corrected the tag wiki to indicate that [arc] is not to be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've edited all the `ar` questions that were for `augmented reality`, and removed the [ar](/questions/tagged/ar).  I don't have the rep to create the tag synonym, or the knowledge to create the tag wiki.

Comment: I edited 3 that you missed, and proposed a (minimal) tag wiki that will at least disambiguate the tag (there's probably no need for anything more detailed; it's a pretty simple utility).