# Disambiguate the [ar] tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“ar” tag on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102587/ar-tag-on-stackoverflow)

The [ar](/questions/tagged/ar) tag is ambiguous; it can refer to both the unix archiver utility and to augmented reality.

Previously, people have [put effort in clearing this up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102587/168333) .

The meaning of the [ar](/questions/tagged/ar) tag is now the Unix `ar` tool, where [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) should be used for augmented reality.

Unfortunately, new questions about augmented reality still get tagged with [ar](/questions/tagged/ar). I have re-tagged a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11860180/revisions) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11896412/revisions), but the problem remains.

I believe that even most programmers, when confronted with the abbreviation "AR", are more likely to think of augmented reality than of the Unix utility.
So I propose that we disambiguate the tag:

1. First, rename [ar](/questions/tagged/ar) to [ar-archiver](/questions/tagged/ar-archiver)
2. After that, make [ar](/questions/tagged/ar) a synonym for [augmented-reality](/questions/tagged/augmented-reality)

Comment: I think your impression that "augmented reality" is what people think of is biased. As is mine! So we'd need real data (for example from the actual use of the tag) to make an informed decision which one should "get" [tag:ar].

Comment: A quick review of the 59 questions showed 13 augmented-reality related questions, three questions about something else entirely ([an R function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695636/internal-na-time-series-zoo-r), [active record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539714/simple-form-bug-with-has-many-through-relation) and [active record again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367545/yii-related-blank-instance-in-view), all retagged now) and the rest about the archiver (43 by my count, but I probably miscounted a bit).

Comment: @JoachimSauer We'd have to look at all the re-tagged questions, too, to determine this. The question I linked is where people went out of their way to re-tag [tag:ar] questions to [tag:augmented-reality]. In the mean time, I see that another question using the [tag:ar] tag for augmented reality has popped up...